# How to extract the data from Alpha Vantage API?

Tags: python, json, extract

I want to make an RSI alert for stocks.

This is the data that Alpha Vantage API responded to my request. I would like to extract the latest RSI whenever I run the code.

In this case, it is 77.0835. As the date and time (i.e. 2020-01-24 14:30) keep changing, is there any way I can get the latest RSI ?

Extract of the response from Alpha Vantage:

```
{
    "Meta Data": {
        "1: Symbol": "tlt",
        "2: Indicator": "Relative Strength Index (RSI)",
        "3: Last Refreshed": "2020-01-24 14:30:46",
        "4: Interval": "60min",
        "5: Time Period": 14,
        "6: Series Type": "close",
        "7: Time Zone": "US/Eastern Time"
    },
    "Technical Analysis: RSI": {
        "2020-01-24 14:30": {
            "RSI": "77.0835"
        },
        "2020-01-24 13:30": {
            "RSI": "78.0121"
        },
        "2020-01-24 12:30": {
            "RSI": "75.8201"
        },
        "2020-01-24 11:30": {
            "RSI": "75.7447"
        },
        "2020-01-24 10:30": {
            "RSI": "73.9965"
        },
        "2020-01-24 09:30": {
            "RSI": "73.8768"
        }
```

Comment: Use the last refreshed datetime to access it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
data = {
    "Meta Data": {
        "1: Symbol": "tlt",
        "2: Indicator": "Relative Strength Index (RSI)",
        "3: Last Refreshed": "2020-01-24 14:30:46",
        "4: Interval": "60min",
        "5: Time Period": 14,
        "6: Series Type": "close",
        "7: Time Zone": "US/Eastern Time"
    },
    "Technical Analysis: RSI": {
        "2020-01-24 14:30": {
            "RSI": "77.0835"
        },
        "2020-01-24 13:30": {
            "RSI": "78.0121"
        },
        "2020-01-24 12:30": {
            "RSI": "75.8201"
        },
        "2020-01-24 11:30": {
            "RSI": "75.7447"
        },
        "2020-01-24 10:30": {
            "RSI": "73.9965"
        },
        "2020-01-24 09:30": {
            "RSI": "73.8768"
        }
    }
}

most_recent_rsi = data['Technical Analysis: RSI'][sorted(data['Technical Analysis: RSI'])[-1]]
```